# PERCENTILE_DISC with Partition by as aggregation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been aggregating a Table with multiple Values for each day into medians, Grouped per Day.

| date | ID | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-11 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-07-11 | 2 | 5 |
| 2021-07-12 | 1 | 12 |
| 2021-07-12 | 2 | 17 |

So far this Query has done the job for me:

```
  SELECT
  Bike.date date,
  PERCENTILE_DISC( IFNULL(Bike.NetB2CRevenue, 0), 0.5 ) OVER(PARTITION BY Bike.date ) 
        AS MedianRevenuePer,

   FROM #Table as Bike
```

Should return:

| date | MedianRevenuePer |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-11 | 3 |
| 2021-07-12 | 14.5 |

Instead, it returns:

| date | MedianRevenuePer |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-11 | 3 |
| 2021-07-11 | 3 |
| 2021-07-12 | 14.5 |
| 2021-07-12 | 14.5 |

Now I know a sort of "Group By2 could solve the issue but this is not applicable in this case as it's part of a bigger Query.

What other methods can I use, besides "Group By"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.date date,
       PERCENTILE_DISC( COALESCE(b.NetB2CRevenue, 0), 0.5 ) OVER (PARTITION BY Bike.date) AS MedianRevenuePer,
FROM #Table b;
```